# Does a trigger on update, that updates its own table, recall the trigger?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, triggers

I have a table called Point.  The table has two columns that we'll deal with, ActualDepth and DesignDepth.  When someone updates ActualDepth I have a trigger that will recalculate the DesignDepths for all of the other points that are near the updated one.

My question then is, Will my trigger be called recursively because other rows in the same table have been updated?  Or, will the fact that the update is happening in a trigger be enough to stop it.  This is the behaviour that I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depends if the system wide option "recursive triggers" is turned on. It's off by default.